# Element not showing/hiding as expected with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, jquery-select2

I have some javascript that shows and hides some help text. Works fine every time unless there is a select2 field present.

HTML:

```
<div class="help-wrap">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label required" for="s2id_autogen1">Occupation</label>
    <div class="select2-container form-control select2 select2-allowclear" id="s2id_milestone_client1_occupation"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return false;" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">   <span class="select2-chosen">Abstractor</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>   <span class="select2-arrow"><b></b></span></a><input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" id="s2id_autogen1"><div class="select2-drop select2-display-none select2-with-searchbox">   <div class="select2-search">       <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input">   </div>   <ul class="select2-results">   </ul></div></div>
    <select class="form-control select2 select2-offscreen" id="milestone_client1_occupation" name="milestone[client1_occupation]" tabindex="-1"><option value="">        </option>
      <option value="001">Abattoir Worker</option>
      <option value="C89">Zoology Consultant</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <span class="fa fa-question-circle"></span>
  <div class="help-text">
    Please select your occupation, if you cannot find an exact match for your occupation then please choose the closest match.
  </div>
</div>
```

Coffeescript:

```
$(document).on 'page:load', ->
  $(document).on 'click', (e) ->
    $('.help-wrap span').each (i,el) ->
      trig = el
      if trig != e.target && !$(trig).has(e.target).length
        $(trig).removeClass('active')
        $(trig).parents('.help-wrap').find('.help-text').hide()
      else
        $(trig).parents('.help-wrap').find('.help-text').toggle()
        $(trig).toggleClass('active')
```

When i click on the span it toggles whether the help-text is shown - this works fine unless a select2 field is present. In which case, nothing happens?

Clicking anywhere on the page other than the span hides the help-text as expected.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the js code as follows:

Using traditional syntax:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $(document).click(function(e) { 
       // Check for left button
       if (e.button == 0) {
         $('.help-wrap span').each(function (i, el) {
            var trig;
            trig = el;
            if (trig !== e.target && !$(trig).has(e.target).length) {
                $(trig).removeClass('active');
                return $(trig).parents('.help-wrap').find('.help-text').hide();
            } else {
                $(trig).parents('.help-wrap').find('.help-text').toggle();
                return $(trig).toggleClass('active');
            }
        });
       }
     });
  });
```

Using coffeescript:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $(document).click (e) ->
    # Check for left button
    if e.button == 0
      $('.help-wrap span').each (i, el) ->
        trig = undefined
        trig = el
        if trig != e.target and !$(trig).has(e.target).length
          $(trig).removeClass 'active'
          $(trig).parents('.help-wrap').find('.help-text').hide()
        else
          $(trig).parents('.help-wrap').find('.help-text').toggle()
          $(trig).toggleClass 'active'
    return
  return
```

This seems to work for me, using this html:

```
<body>
  <div class="help-wrap">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label required" for="s2id_autogen1">Occupation</label>

   <div class="select2-container form-control select2 select2-allowclear" id="s2id_milestone_client1_occupation"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return false;" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">   <span class="select2-chosen">Abstractor</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>   <span class="select2-arrow"><b></b></span></a><input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" id="s2id_autogen1"><div class="select2-drop select2-display-none select2-with-searchbox">   <div class="select2-search">       <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input">   </div>   <ul class="select2-results">   </ul></div></div>


    <select class="form-control select2 select2-offscreen" id="milestone_client1_occupation" name="milestone[client1_occupation]" tabindex="-1"><option value="">        </option>
      <option value="001">Abattoir Worker</option>
      <option value="C89">Zoology Consultant</option>
    </select>

  </div>
  <span class="fa fa-question-circle"></span>
  <div class="help-text">
    Please select your occupation, if you cannot find an exact match for your occupation then please choose the closest match.
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Cheers but doesn't seem to work. Clicking the span does not toggle the help text. display:block is added inline to the help-text element but does not get changed to display:none @randall-valenciano

Answer (score 0):

So turned out the selector wasn't specific enough.

Changed `$('.help-wrap span')` to something more specific.

Thanks for helping